# Get information from a form to pass two variables that will be used on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am on my bootcamp`s final lap and am building my final project.

I need to get a "start date" and an "end date" from the user so I can setup the lenght of time on the chart on the same page.
How can I store the information provided by the user on a variable that will feed the query?

I added this form:

```rb
<%= form_with do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :start_date, "Start Date" %>
  <%= form.date_field :start_date %>
  <%= form.label :end_date, "End Date" %>
  <%= form.date_field :end_date %>
<% end %>

<%= line_chart Weight.pluck(:date, :value), xmin: start_date, xmax: end_date %>
```

That rendered the following:

[image]

How can I save both dates separately (or be able to separate them later), so I can use them on the chart object?

Comment: Its very unclear what you're struggling with here. In Rails you would typically use a model which you bind to the form and use to persist the data. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-article

Comment: I honestly am not sure how to be more clear. I need to be able to manage dates on the chart. And will not create a new model for it, as I don`t neet to create new model instances in the database to setup date range for  the x-axis of a chart.

Answer (score 0):

As your form targets the "current" page, you can probably just use the `params` object to pass the user selected dates to the chart, something like:

```rb
line_chart Weight.pluck(:date, :value), xmin: params[:start_date], xmax: params[:end_date]
```

Comment: That is what I needed to do. Plus, I added this so the form could get the values and pass to the chart:
form_with url: weights_path, method: :get,

Comment: Happy to help @Marina, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer helped you to solve the issue, please mark it as accepted or give it some credit (upvote).